# Android: How to create a reminder such as google keep reminder

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to add a reminder to my android app such as [Google Keep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep&hl=en) app reminder for notes, as you know in Gkeep you can set reminder for your notes by set date (Today,Tomorrow,Next same day or Pick a date from Calendar) and set time (Morning, Afternoon,Evening, Night or pick a time from Clock).
Any help?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer! and share it with you because i think its nothing to do with Mechanical Turk :)).
in MainActivity:

```
final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
final Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();   
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 22);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 5);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
long when = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,when, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

and the AlarmReciver class :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Calendar now = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            Notification.Builder mBuilder = 
                    new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setSound(android.provider.Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("my title")
                    .setContentText("my text");             
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

And to cancel the reminder :

```
if (alarmManager!= null) {
                alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
            }
```